# Get url fragment by phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I need to get url fragment of current url and put fragment (hash) into php variable. Like this:

```
$current_url = exec(phantomjs script.js);
```

When I use `window.location.href` in `script.js` file, It shows the script.js url.
I need to get Current url of php file whith it's fragment(hash).

How can I do this. Please help.

UPDATE:
I need get URL of current php file that phantomjs is execute like this: examle.com/need_url_of_this_page.php#11111

Comment: what current url? what is an origin of that url? what are you talking about? url from webpage from inside that script or what?

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking about but I guess it's about this in your `script.js`:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
  var url = page.url;
  console.log('URL: ' + url);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: This code shows phantomjs.org URL. I need get URL of current php file that phantomjs is execute like this:
http://examle.com/need_url_of_this_page.php#11111

Comment: but what `phantomjs` has to do with it then? just use `$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` in `PHP` itself. Please note that you can't get hash. It's not being send to the server, only interpreted browser side.

Comment: I need to get the hash.

Comment: you can't, as I said, it is not being send to the server at all, you would have to do it in javascript, convert the url to `$_GET` instead of hash, like `original_url#hash` to `original_url?hash=$hash` and then send the request to the server